# Doctrine - Set One Object Equal to Another

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

In Doctrine / Php / MySQL, im trying to pull one record from the DB that is in Table A.  I then want to take that row, and insert it into Table B (which has the exact same structure as Table A).

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two tables have *identical* structures I think you can do something like:

```
$B = new TableB();
$B->fromArray($A->toArray());
$B->save();
```

this is ok only for few records. If you need to copy a lot of records and need performances use PDO with insert into B/select from A type queries!